# How can I change icon for send button on direct reply Android

Tags: android, remote-input

I have created a notification, with an action with `RemoteInput` to add a note into the specific entry of my app like this:

```
        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("key_add_note")
                .setLabel("add note")
                .build();

        NotificationCompat.Action action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_action_edit,
                        "add-note", replyPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .build();

        notification.addAction(action);
```

[image]

and this shows me an input field on performing `ADD-NOTE` action like this:

[image]

here I don't want to use the default send icon and want to change it so it suits my action.

so far I didn't come across anything to achieve this, let me know if its possible? and how to do it.

Comment: It should be `R.drawable.ic_action_edit`, what are you seeing when you run your code?

Comment: @JakeSteam that icon won't show up anywhere with my configuration and it is for the action button `ADD-NOTE` and not for the remote input. check the updates in question for how it looks like

Comment: Have You found any solution for this?

Comment: @iknow not at the time I was looking for it. stopped looking since